# Identifying position transfer function for a DC motor

Tags: control-system, electric-machine

I am trying to identify a simple position/speed system based on the inputs and outputs using a DC motor equipped with a qudrature encoder.For the soft i am using   xcorr and arduino blocks to apply a closed loop control without any controller .

I wanted to know if my scheme is correct knowing that i am  converting a position (100 cm for example )into a pwm signal after substracting the actual position from the desired one as shown in the picture.

[image: xcorr diagram]

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way: Just use the simple linear DC motor model,

$$V=Ri+L \frac {di}{dt} + K_T\frac{d\theta}{dt}$$
$$\tau=K_Ti$$
$$\tau=J\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+B\frac{d\theta}{dt}$$

and use the motor manufacturer's specs: winding resistance,R, inductance,L, rotor inertia,J, torque constant, KT , and viscous damping factor, B.

Comment: Actually,I am using a Pololu motor and they don t seem to include  all the specs.

Comment: That's frustrating. If they include any of the specs it will be of help. You can at least measure the winding resistance with a meter. I use an HP 35670A dynamic signal analyzer and white noise excitation to get a real time Bode analysis & fit the data to a rational polynomial transfer function that's constrained for the model order above. But you do have to close the loop just to stabilize the motor, then use the analyzer math functions to get back to open loop. Using proportional gain is best in this case. You need to make sure the gain is large enough to get a response.

Comment: ... but not too large to make it unstable. The analyzer includes coherence measurement as a quality check on your measurement.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all the main elements exists for a position controller.

Not much can be said as there are specific blocks there like the encoder ...

1) Your feedback - The quadrature encoder

2) The feedback gain

3) The demand - modelled as a step

4) Error block - to provide position error

5)  Ratelimiters?  - although you missed a trick by just using one and forking the output, save on resource

5) output driving a pwm register and the inverse driving the other

What could be missing is some Proportional gain at the output of the summing block. You need to change a position error into a voltage demand, a demand that will eventually induce a torque to rotate

one thing I will add... control block discipline... that is not the greatest of visual representations of a simple P loop